# Pushing number of clicks to an object with the key

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

please how can I push the number of clicks into an object together with their keys from a specified value? the code I'm working with below. for example; it becomes something like Var Value_object = {contestant_one: 4, contestant_two: 7,...}

```js
var total = document.querySelector(".Fixed_number");
var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#minus");
var allSpan = document.getElementById('displayvalue');
var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#plus");
var value_object = {};

plusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(total.innerText) > 0) {
            item.nextElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.nextElementSibling.innerText) + 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) - 1;

        }
    };

});

minusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    let variable;
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) > 0) {
            item.previousElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) - 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) + 1;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="Fixed_number">10</div>


    <form>
        <label for=""> Contestant_One
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus"   type="button">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus"  type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>




    <form>
        <label for=""> Contestant_Two
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>


    <form>
        <label for=""> Contestant_Three
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>




    <form>
        <label for="">Contestant_Four
        <div id="">
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="displayvalue">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
        </label>
    </form>


push the number of clicks into an object with their key from a specified value? the code I'm working with below.

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Having duplicate `id` attribute values is invalid in HTML.

Comment: the `label` element should be accessible in your handlers via `item.parentNode.previousElementSibling` so you can dig out the contestant name and then use that to store/retrieve from your object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
const fixedNum = document.querySelector('#Fixed_number');
let fixedNumCount = 10;
const value_object = {};

function handleClick(e) {
    const targetEl = e.target.type;
    const contestant = e.target.parentElement.id;
    const operation = e.target.dataset.operation;
    if (targetEl === 'button') {
        if (value_object[contestant] === undefined) {
            if (operation === 'plus') {
                value_object[contestant] = 1; 
                fixedNumCount--;
            } else {
                value_object[contestant] = -1;
                fixedNumCount++;
            }
        } else {
            if (operation === 'plus') {
                value_object[contestant] = ++value_object[contestant];
                fixedNumCount--
            } else {
                value_object[contestant] = --value_object[contestant];
                fixedNumCount++
            }
        }
        document.querySelector(`div#${contestant} span`).textContent = value_object[contestant]
        fixedNum.textContent = fixedNumCount;
    }
}
```

Note: I just changed the duplicate ids to class since, as @trincot mentioned, you shouldn't use the same id on more than one element.

```html
    <body>
        <div id="Fixed_number">10</div>
        <form>
            <label for="">Contestant_One
                <div id="contestant_one">
                    <button data-operation="plus" type="button">+</button>
                        <span class="displayvalue">0</span>
                    <button data-operation="minus"  type="button">-</button>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>

        <form>
            <label for="">Contestant_Two
                <div id="contestant_two">
                    <button data-operation="plus" type="button">+</button>
                        <span class="displayvalue">0</span>
                    <button data-operation="minus" type="button">-</button>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>

        <form>
            <label for="">Contestant_Three
                <div id="contestant_three">
                    <button data-operation="plus" type="button">+</button>
                        <span class="displayvalue">0</span>
                    <button data-operation="minus" type="button">-</button>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>

        <form>
            <label for="">Contestant_Four
                <div id="contestant_four">
                    <button data-operation="plus" type="button">+</button>
                        <span class="displayvalue">0</span>
                    <button data-operation="minus" type="button">-</button>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: this works but my fixed value is not functioning, the fixed value is to reduce when the plus button is clicked and increase when minus is clicked also, it returns for the only contestant_one clicked.  The earlier code works exactly how I want but just need to push the contestants to the object with the number of times they were clicked.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Akinyemi - I didn't see anything in your question about the `Fixed_number` (and it appears to not be "fixed" but that's a separate, semantic issue) but I just made some edits and fixed some edge case bugs from my original answer so see if that works for you. I didn't try to stick to your JavaScript in my answer since it just seems a little indirect but maybe I'm just not understanding exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help me out. Your code actually work perfectly but the fixed value is to reduce when plus button is clicked and increase when minus button is clicked. For instance: fixed =10, when I click plus button my display value should give 1 and fixed reduced to 9 and when minus is clicked, my display value should be 0 and fixed go back to 10. It works like that for all the contestants. Then I should be able to push to the empty object above to hold all the contestants score out of the fixed value. Like display object = {contestant_one: 5,...}

Comment: Oh I guess I got the fixed part backwards. I've now reversed the incrementors and decrementors

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to get what you want. Well, technically two different ways!

This is the simplest solution I can think of that gets you the values in the format you want without impacting any other functionality. Since it's basic javascript, this can be built on and improved.

Similarly to the other answer, i've removed your duplicate IDs but opted to make each inputs span ID unique rather than a class.

```js
var total = document.querySelector(".Fixed_number");
var minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#minus");
var plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#plus");
var GetTotal = document.getElementById('get_all');

var value1 = document.getElementById('Contestant_One');
var value2 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Two');
var value3 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Three');
var value4 = document.getElementById('Contestant_Four');

plusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(total.innerText) > 0) {
            item.nextElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.nextElementSibling.innerText) + 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) - 1;

            //METHOD 1. Collect the info on detecting the last + input has reduced Fixed Number to zero.
            if(parseInt(total.innerText) == 0) {
                var TotalAll = value1.id + ": " + value1.innerText + ", " + 
                               value2.id + ": " + value2.innerText + ", " + 
                               value3.id + ": " + value3.innerText + ", " + 
                               value4.id + ": " + value4.innerText; 
                alert(TotalAll);
            }
        }
    };
});

minusBtn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) > 0) {
            item.previousElementSibling.innerText = parseInt(item.previousElementSibling.innerText) - 1;
            total.innerText = parseInt(total.innerText) + 1;
        }
    };
});

//METHOD 2, just use a button or on submit to collect it manually, which can be done regardless of Fixed_number value. 
GetTotal.onclick = function() {
  var TotalAll = value1.id + ": " + value1.innerText + ", " + 
             value2.id + ": " + value2.innerText + ", " + 
             value3.id + ": " + value3.innerText + ", " + 
             value4.id + ": " + value4.innerText; 
  alert(TotalAll);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="Fixed_number">10</div>

    <form>
        <label>Contestant_One</label>
        <div>
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_One">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form>
        <label>Contestant_Two</label>
        <div>
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Two">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <form>
        <label>Contestant_Three</label>
        <div>
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Three">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form>
        <label>Contestant_Four</label>
        <div>
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
            <span id="Contestant_Four">0</span>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>

Push the number of clicks into an object with their key from a specified value.

    <div id="all_total">
        <button id="get_all" type="submit">Get Totals</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```